# if item not in list strange behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, glob

So I am trying to iterate over a folder of events with a subfolder of clients, to create two lists one of event names and one of customer names. It all works fine until the last folder which then ignores the if statement after the first customer. The events list works out fine, it is the customer list that does not.
Using python3 in anaconda on windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import glob

path = 'Z:\\VBox_Backup\\**\\*.vbo'

events = []
customers = []
for vbo_path in glob.glob(path, recursive=True):
    path_list = vbo_path.split('\\')
    event = path_list[2].upper()
    customer = path_list[3].title()
    if event not in events:
        events.append(path_list[2])
    if customer not in customers:
        customers.append(path_list[3])

if 'GT4' in customers:
    print('yay')
else:
    print('nay')

print(customers)
```

There is no error message, just duplicates of names in the customer folder, all from the last folder only. Unfortunately, I can't provide the raw data due to nature of the clients. Can anyone see any stupid mistakes that I may have made?

Comment: you are checking that `event` is not in the list but then adding `path_list[2]` to the list.  `path_list[2]` may or may not already be in the list when it gets added, wouldn't you want to just `.append(event)` instead?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that looks like it - the difference being that `event` is uppercased and `path_list[2]` isn't... Looks like the same potential problem with `customer` as well

Comment: Thanks Tadhg, I didn't even need to try it to know you were correct, and of course yes you were, thank you.